# Having trouble with a UIPickerView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have an app with a `UIPickerView` and whenever a certain row of the picker view is selected, a table view below it updates with relevant information. My problem is that whenever the app first opens, the table view is empty even though the first row of the picker view is highlighted/selected by default. I have to scroll down and then back up to the first row in order for it to register as truly selected, and for the table view to update properly.

Is there a way to make it so that the first row automatically gets selected so I don't have to scroll down and back up every time? I know there's a `selectRow()` function, but that doesn't work. It just does the same thing. In other words, the row "looks" selected, but it's not actually registering that way. Does anyone know if this is just how it is, or is there a way to bypass it?

EDIT: Here's my `didSelectRow` code for the picker view:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView:UIPickerView, didSelectRow row:Int, inComponent component:Int)
{
    let currentState = abbvsList[statePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:(NSURL(string:"http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/\(currentState).php?x=0") as! URL))!
    alerts = []
    exps = []
    sev = []
    summ = []
    eff = []
    urg = []
    cert = []
    link = []
    latList = []
    longList = []
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    alertsTable.reloadData()
    if(alerts.isEmpty) {
        alertsTable.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        alertsTable.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: show your picker `didSelect` Code.

Comment: @Mr.Bista Alright, I updated it! If you need any more, let me know.

Comment: Where do you load your picker view? or you have predefined array to load?

Comment: @Mr.Bista I have a predefined array of the 50 US states that populate the PickerView. So when the app first opens, Alabama is selected, but the TableView isn't showing what it's supposed to until I scroll away and then back.

Comment: show code where you did " Alabama is selected".

Comment: There isn't any such code. The default behavior for a PickerView is for the first row to be highlighted by default, correct? I don't think I ever specified Alabama to be selected first, that's just how it was automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initial method to load data, Try calling it inside `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

```
//It should be called after the picker view is loaded.
func loadPickerView(){
    if abbvsList.count > 0 {
        let currentState = abbvsList[0]// get the first element of array
        parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:(NSURL(string:"http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/\(currentState).php?x=0") as! URL))!
        alerts = []
        exps = []
        sev = []
        summ = []
        eff = []
        urg = []
        cert = []
        link = []
        latList = []
        longList = []
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        alertsTable.reloadData()
        if(alerts.isEmpty) {
            alertsTable.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            alertsTable.isHidden = false
        }
    }else{
        //picker view data is empty
    }
}
```